# Is it possible to use an iOS private API to modify restrictions from within apps?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I'm searching for a way to add any websites to a blacklist on restrictions on *Settings* app on iOS. This is archivable manually by tapping *Settings* app, go to *General* and then go to *Restriction*, turn on *Enable Restrictions*, go to *Websites*, then change it to *Limit content for adults* (the exact words would likely not be matched as I use Spanish on iPhone).

However, adding any websites here is so much of a pain as it doesn't sync with other iDevices and Mac. So I rather want to create an app for personal use to block any websites.

But I didn't find any such seemingly appropriate methods in [a list of private API frameworks](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks).

Is it possible to use such API in iOS? Or otherwise is there any other workaround to set it programatically on the app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any private API to do this but if you're looking for private APIs that means you have some control over the devices you install the app on (because it couldn't be published on the appstore).

One solution could be to supervise those devices and then use a MDM service like HexnodeMDM. They offer an API to create and assign policies to your devices.

I must warn this is only hypothetical, I'm a HexnodeMDM user but I haven't tried using their API yet :)